# How do I use python to graph elements of a large CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, urllib

I'm currently looking at 'Quandl' for importing stock data into python by using the CSV format. However, I'm stuck trying to find a way of selecting parameters (i.e. picking out 2 columns to plot on a graph - for example 'Date' and 'Close Price', and filtering out the rows so I'm only plotting the last 100 days of trading prices).

```
import urllib
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/V.csv?api_key=Fa1P1yZLGnGSsXktrvzL'
With open(url, ‘rb’) as f:
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print row

csv = urllib.urlopen(url).read().decode()
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    csv = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar=' ', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, skiprows=1)

x, y = np.loadtxt('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/V.csv?api_key=Fa1P1yZLGnGSsXktrvzL',
         dtype={'names': ('Date', 'Price'),
                'formats': ('%d/%m%Y', 'i6')},
         unpack=True)

plt.plot(x, y, label='Stock Values')

plt.title('End of Day Visa Stock Prices for US Exchange')
plt.ylabel('Stock Price')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

That's what I have so far but cannot get it anywhere near a working model. It would be great to hear how to fix this and maybe adapt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/). It is waaaay easier :

```
url = 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/EOD/V.csv?api_key=Fa1P1yZLGnGSsXktrvzL'
df = pd.read_csv(url, parse_dates=True,index_col=0)
df = df.rename(columns={'Close':'Stock Price'})
s = df['Stock Price']

s_to_plot = s.sort_index(ascending=True).tail(100)
ax = s_to_plot.plot(title='End of Day Visa Stock Prices for US Exchange')
ax.set_ylabel('Stock Price')
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling to import pandas even though I had it installed through anaconda, but finally managed to resolve it. I will start applying this to some of the other files on Quandl too.